# Layout issues with ssrs-2008

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011

I have some trouble with the layout of a custom invoice report for CRM 2011 based on fetch xml, created in ssrs-2008.

One dataset can contain several invoices. The details have on parent group, grouped on Invoice Number. 
The invoice header is located in a rectangle in the header row of the group and is repeated to get the report header on all pages.
The invoice footer is located in a rectangle in the footer row of the group. The parent group is followed a pagebreak to make sure that every invoice starts on a new page. So far so good...

My problem now is that the invoice footer has to be placed at the bottom of the last page, and the details can only have a certain height. If the height is exceeded it must continue on the next page. Is there any way that I can achieve this in ssrs-2008?

I already tried playing with the number of lines in the details, but since the line height is dynamic (a invoice line description may need several text lines) this won't work.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried setting Can Grow to false?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to limit the number of rows on each page? If yes then follow below steps,

1] Go to properties of table

2] Go to Groups Tab and add group (put this group on top of all other existing groups)

3] Add Expression =Ceiling((RowNumber(Nothing))/15) (15 will be the number of rows per page.)

4] Check Page Break at end checked and un check Include group header and Include group footer check boxes.